# Getting error after adding SSL configuration [Apache Ignite]

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, ignite, gridgain

I'm trying to add SSL in my client / server nodes but i'm getting a "Handshake timed out" from the client side and a "*Failed to process selector key*" "*Closing NIO session because of unhandled exception*" from the server side. I don't know if I am doing things correctly...
I'm using java 11 + ignite 2.7.6 + gridgain 8.7.6

**For the keystore creation:**
keytool -genkey -alias server-alias -keyalg RSA -keypass password -storepass password -keystore serverkeystore.jks

keytool -genkey -alias client-alias -keyalg RSA -keypass password -storepass password -keystore clientkeystore.jks

**Exporting the cer into its own file:**
keytool -export -alias server-alias -storepass password -file server.cer -keystore serverkeystore.jks

keytool -export -alias client-alias -storepass password -file client.cer -keystore clientkeystore.jks

**Add the certs to the server trust store**
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias server-alias -file server.cer -keystore publicserverkeystore.jks -keypass password -storepass password

keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias client-alias -file client.cer -keystore publicserverkeystore.jks -keypass password -storepass password

**Add the certs to the client trust store**
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias client-alias -file client.cer -keystore publicclientkeystore.jks -keypass password -storepass password

keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias server-alias -file server.cer -keystore publicclientkeystore.jks -keypass password -storepass password

**Now in the java client node side:**

```
    ClientConnectorConfiguration cliConnCfg = new ClientConnectorConfiguration();
    cliConnCfg.setJdbcEnabled(false);
    cliConnCfg.setOdbcEnabled(false);
    cliConnCfg.setThinClientEnabled(false);
    cliConnCfg.setSslEnabled(true);
    cliConnCfg.setSslClientAuth(true);

    igniteConfiguration.setClientConnectorConfiguration(cliConnCfg);

    SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStoreFilePath("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.2\\lib\\security\\clientkeystore.jks");
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("password".toCharArray());
    sslContextFactory.setTrustStoreFilePath("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.2\\lib\\security\\publicclientkeystore.jks");
    sslContextFactory.setTrustStorePassword("password".toCharArray());
    igniteConfiguration.setSslContextFactory(sslContextFactory);
```

**Now in the java server node side:**

```
ClientConnectorConfiguration cliConnCfg = new ClientConnectorConfiguration();
cliConnCfg.setJdbcEnabled(false);
cliConnCfg.setOdbcEnabled(false);
cliConnCfg.setThinClientEnabled(false);
cliConnCfg.setSslEnabled(true);
cliConnCfg.setSslClientAuth(true);

igniteConfiguration.setClientConnectorConfiguration(cliConnCfg);

SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
sslContextFactory.setKeyStoreFilePath("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.2\\lib\\security\\serverkeystore.jks");
sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("password".toCharArray());
sslContextFactory.setTrustStoreFilePath("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.2\\lib\\security\\publicserverkeystore.jks");
sslContextFactory.setTrustStorePassword("password".toCharArray());

igniteConfiguration.setSslContextFactory(sslContextFactory);
```

Comment: So you have a client, a server, and perhaps some thin clients as well. Please clarify which ones of these work normally and which aren't, otherwise it's very unclear.

Comment: Hi alamar, i don't have any thin clients! I got 2 projects, both with ignite configs but 1 of them is "setClientMode(true)". If I remove SSL config everything works fine. To make requests (get or posts) i'm using postman.

Comment: Why do you have client connector configuration then? It is for thin client only. Of course, you need to also secure it, as well as jetty and connectorconfiguration. But it won't do anything when you have just two nodes.
Please provide logs from nodes, without quiet mode (-v)

Comment: Best way to share the log pls?

Comment: Alamar here u go
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oFCJryj4OwdNNUp4lFuKahpEx9QP5DP3?usp=sharing

Comment: I recommend upgrading to 8.7.13 since there were some SSL fixes. Otherwise it is possible that client node does not trust server node's certificate. I recommend enabling Java-side SSL logging to see what's going on. Also consider adding `-Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1.2"` on both client and server - this is what was fixed in later releases. It should not affect JDK 11, but it's worth trying.

Comment: Omg you are the man, i add the "-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2" on client and server, and it works :) Thank you so much! And btw I removed the ClientConnectorConfiguration aswell, as you said. How do I give u a thumbs up? :)